# при запуске node start.js в консоли появляется syntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Tags: node.js

В консоли Windows 7 пытаюсь запустить код из файла start.js командой "***node start.js***". В результате выдается "syntaxError: Unexpected end of input". Не могу понять - почему. Помогите, пожалуйста разобраться.

Файл start.js

```
var http = require("http");
http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  console.log("HTTP works!");
}); // end createServer
http.listen(8080);
```

Код взят из книги К. Сухова "Node.js путеводитель по технологии"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вообще, это ошибка синтаксиса. Вы где-то либо символ оставили, либо скобку не закрыли. Обычно в тексте ошибки указан символ, который вызвал ошибку или строка и столбец с ошибкой. Скиньте полную ошибку или поправьте сами.

Но вообще у вас сервер итак не заведется.

Либо книга написана под старую версию node, либо Сухов напортачил. `http.createServer` возвращает вам экземпляр сервера, который вы будете прослушивать на указанном вами порту.

```
var http = require("http");
var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  console.log("HTTP works!");
}); // end createServer
server.listen(8080);
```

Comment: Набрал ваш код. Все заработало. Возможно, я ошибаюсь, но, как я понял, метод listen принадлежит методу CreateServer, a не модулю http напрямую. Спасибо за подсказку.

Comment: Возможно, вы путаетесь в терминах. Методы не принадлежат методам. Они принадлежат объектам. `http.createServer` создает как раз объект типа `http.Server` и возвращает его из функции. Возвращенный сервер мы записываем в переменную `server`. У объекта `http.Server` определены свои методы, среди которых есть и `listen`.

Comment: Ссылка на документацию https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/http.html#http_http_createserver_options_requestlistener